# Auto Generate Key

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

how can I select my last ProductCode (Primary Key) in ProductInformation table in my database and adding +1 on it and put it on my text field to make my Add Product form to become auto generated? Here is my current code on adding a product.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int Confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to add this product?");
    if(Confirm == 0) {
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO ProductInformation VALUES (?,?)";
        String ConnectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/SystemProject?"+"user=root&password=";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connect = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
            PS = Connect.prepareStatement(SQL);
            PS.setString(1, ProductCodeText.getText());
            PS.setString(2, ProductNameText.getText());
            if("".equals(ProductNameText.getText()) || "".equals(ProductCodeText.getText()) || ("".equals(ProductNameText.getText()) && ("".equals(ProductCodeText.getText())))) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill all the information needed","Error in adding product",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                AddProductForm APF = new AddProductForm();
                APF.setVisible(true);
                this.hide();
            }
            else {
                int Count = PS.executeUpdate(); 
                if(Count > 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Product saved");
                    ProductCodeText.setText("");
                    ProductNameText.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't duplicate product code","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

What will I add to my code to make it work that way. Thanks guys.

Comment: It's a bit late to be validating and displaying GUI dialog boxes when you've already got the connection, prepared the statement, and set the values. All that should precede anything to do with the database.

Comment: I just recreated my database sir. What will I do to my table and the column on it. Please guide me. I only need ProductCode and ProductName. My only problem is how to set my textfield with the last ProductCode + 1 on it to become unique. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

If not, depending on what IDE you are using, most IDE like `NetBeans` or `Visual Studio`, it allows you to set the field with auto increment via their user interface.

Comment: Where do I put that command sir? In phpmyadmin? Btw, im using Netbeans and XAMPP. Thanks sir.

Comment: @JohndaveDavid If you are using NetBeans, you don't even have to use the codes. Create a table, add the fields, the sql command will be auto generated. Before you commit those auto generated commands, right click your primary key field (if not right click, explore the properties of the table), set auto increment to true.

Comment: Sorry sir i'm new at netbeans, where will I create a table? Should I put it on my form? Btw, add me on facebook sir. I really need help. Thanks sir. Fb.me/DForDeyb